# AdS-CFT on a torus

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft, wilson-loop

A gauge theory at finite volume and temperature on a space like $S^{n-1}\times S^1$ is supposed to be dual to a string theory on either $AdS_{n+1}$ or a Schwarzschild black hole in $AdS_{n+1}$, with a Hawking-Page phase transition between the two depending on the size of the $S^{n-1}$ compared to the $S^1$ (see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9803131).

What if instead of $S^{n-1}$ the gauge theory is defined on a spatial torus so that we can consider Wilson loops wrapping around the spatial directions? Is there a known geometry on the AdS side that this corresponds to?